# Is it possible to just import DataFrame from pandas and the function to read excel?

Tags: pandas

I want to inport DataFrame and the function to read excelfiles. But I dont want to import all modules with "import pandas as pd". Is it possible?

Comment: only if you import the necessary class eg `read_excel`. Only with `from pandas import DataFrame` not possible

Comment: Thank you. How do I import the class "read_excel"?

Comment: `from pandas import read_excel` , `read_excel(file....)` however after reading the excel if you want to do any kind of processing , you will need other classes under pandas which you will have to manually import one by one. better is `import pandas as pd` and then access whatever class needed

Comment: thank you. I imported it, but I cant read it with: "df = read_excel('Test.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet1, skiprows = 3)[:-1]"

Comment: you will have to provide the full path of the file, eg: `C:\\Users\\...\\Test.xlsx..`